# get id of spinner item clicked which is set at server side

Tags: android

I am getting json response like this from php server

`{ "optrdata":[ {"operator_id":"1","operator_name":"AIRTEL","operator_status":"1"},{"operator_id":"2", "operator_name":"IDEA","operator_status":"1"},....]}`

I am also able to set operator_name data on spinner.

Now the question is I want operator_id of operator_name when I/User will click on operator name how can I get that.

Comment: create a model class for the operator and make an arraylist of model class to store all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the model class as following.

```
public class Operator{
  public String id,name,status;
}
```

Now Create an ArrayList like this,

`ArrayList<Operator> operatorsList = new ArrayList<Operator>();`

At the time of parsing this object

```
for(int i =0;i<jsonArray.lenth();i++){
  Operator op = new Operator();
  op.name = //get your string here
  op.id = //get from json object
  op.status = //get from json object
  operatorList.add(op);
}
```

and finally fill the spinner from looping through this array list and after selecting any item get the data according to the position of selection you can simply get the data from this arraylist with

`Operator op = operatorsList.get(positionOfSpinnerSelection)`

and the get the id and name with

```
String name = op.name;
String id = op.id;
```